Is there a native postgres function or operator to display IPv6 full representation
I have a database that houses a mix of IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. For the IPv6 specifically, we have some users inputting the addresses as their full representatin while others input the shortened versions.
Is there a way to always get the full representation from a query?
Example:
I have a record with the following IP address: 2001:db8::8a2e:370:7334
If I do a simple select, for IP address column, I'll get 2001:db8::8a2e:370:7334 as a result.
Is there a way to get 2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334 instead even though the stored value is shortened?

Show the exact data type of the column and your version of Postgres, please.
